# Local module import works fine with ipython but fails with python

Tags: python, ipython, python-import

I have a package `my_package/` which contains two modules `module1.py` and `module2.py`, where `module2.py` contains:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)  # for troubleshooting

from my_package import module1
```

Running:

```
python -c "from my_package import module2"
```

from the parent directory works fine. However I would also like to be able to run `module2.py` for unit testing. Running:

```
ipython my_package/module2.py
```

also works fine. However trying to run with python:

```
python my_package/module2.py
```

fails (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'`). In both cases, `/home/user/my_project/my_package` appears in sys.path. My versions of python and ipython are the same (3.7.4). Adding `__init__.py` in `my_package/` did not help.

Why does this happen, and how do I solve this issue?

Comment: It works in `python` if you put the current directory into the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (and export it from your shell).

Comment: I guess that for whatever reason, it is decided in `ipython` to include the current directory in the search path even if it is not there explicitly (so if you are in the `mypackage/` directory it will work), whereas with `python` it needs to be there explicitly (or at least `.`).

Comment: You could work around it with the following in `my_package/module2.py`:  `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))` - though I can't help thinking it is better to just ensure that your `PYTHONPATH` is set correctly.

Comment: Once your package is actually installed (e.g. into a virtual environment you are using) you should be fine anyway because that will be in your `PYTHONPATH`. If you are still developing it, and you have a `setup.py`, consider using `python setup.py develop`.

Comment: You don’t *want* `my_package` on `sys.path`—it’s not a directory that contains top-level modules!